# Count erros messages in multiple files per day

Tags: bash, shell, grep

So i have a log file that display err|error messages that i wanna count every day

```
cat user.log | grep 'err|error' | wc -l
```

gimme almos all that i need whoever there are other log files that are zip so

```
zcat user.log.* | grep 'err|error' | wc -l
```

also almost there

so here is where im stuck, i need to check every log.zip file check if has any error message of today date  in multiple files and also on user.log that is my current file collecting the errors

so i need to check over 50 user.log.Z files count all line that has today date 
Oct  8 00:00:00 until 23:59:59 
and my user.log

gratz in advance

EDIT-------------

solverd with

```
 DATE=`date "+%b %e"` ;find /var/adm/ ! -path /var/adm/ -prune -name "user.log*" -prune  -mtime -1 -exec zgrep "$DATE" {} \; |grep "user:err|error" |wc -l
```

Comment: And the command does not work?

Comment: it returns all the errors of up to week ago, i need only today date and if only 1 line has today date it must be counted and sum into all other count of every file

Comment: Does lines in files have dates? Does logrotate append current date to the filename? What is the format?

Comment: logrotate is by size and dont put date on the name ex;user.log.0.Z,user.log.1.Z,user.log.2.Z. log 2 for instance only has a few line of today date while log 1 have morning from today and 0 afternoon and so on

Comment: find . -name "*.log*" -mtime -1 -exec zgrep "err|error" {} \; this is my latest code but its stilll collect from the whole file and not by today date so now still remains to limitate to show only lines from today date, trying to think awk for that

Comment: Ok, but how are the lines formatted. Can you show example input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the date is part of the filename, append it (whereever it's added by logrotate):

```
zcat -f user.log.* user.log-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).* | grep 'err|error' | wc -l
zcat -f user.log user.log.$(date +%Y-%m-%d).* | grep 'err|error' | wc -l
```

`grep` can also count, `zgrep` can also process compressed files, so a bit shorter:

```
zgrep -c 'err|error' user.log user.log.$(date +%Y-%m-%d)*
```

If the date is not part of the filename, you need to process all files and filter out all lines with a different date:

```
zgrep $(date +%Y-%m-%d) file ... | grep -c 'err|error'
zgrep $(date "+%b  %d") file ... | grep -c 'err|error'
```

Or using awk:

```
# Assumes the date is in the first field, like "2018-10-09 ... err|error ..."
zcat ... | awk 'BEGIN{d=strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}/err\|error/&&$01==d{c++}END{print c}'
```

Comment: so my user.log dont have dates its just numeric like user.log.0.Z-user.log.49.Z goes so i cant colect via date cause like log 0 to 4 has error from today

Comment: @GrupoImpacta See edit. If that still doesn't help, please provide sample log lines, because it becomes a bit laborious without.

Comment: Oct  9 11:00:03 host user:err|error IIB[8913006]: IBM Integration Bus v10007 (bd.name) [Thread 24428] (Msg 3/3) BIP3184S: An exception occurred whilst sending reply data to the client: 'https...'

Comment: just a obs note it has 2 spaces beetwen oct and 9

Comment: @GrupoImpacta See edit. But anyways, all these solutions should have given you enough information to be able to do it yourself.

Comment: thanks man still dont work even with "+%b  %d" it show lines with yesterday date, but im gonna try to implement ur solution

Comment: @GrupoImpacta If you'd only put some sample data in your question I would have saved a lot of time... Like so it's quite arduous. Just check the output of `date "+%b  %d"`. If you grep only for that, then no lines from yesterday can be in the output. (BTW I tried it here and I added fictional data from yesterday and tomorrow. It worked.)

Comment: Oh, one more thing: Since the date is (unusually) `9` and not `09` you have to remember, that `Oct  1` would also match `Oct  10`. So you have to add another character (or `[^0-9]`) there.

Comment: thanks man is the god damn date that is trying to read 09 and dont have so he mess up the code